# What happened to Chiphacker? Electronics Exchange?

Tags: discussion

Where did Chiphacker and Electronics Exchange go?

Answer (score 7):

Geez, no heads-up?  I miss the octopus.

Answer (score 5):

R.I.P Electropus!

Comment: Most all of the answers to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/671/ have `alt text' instead of the image, and nothing is available on Google, either!   Maybe Electropus is just hiding?

Answer (score 5):

As described in the original [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2651?phase=definition), Chiphacker.com has become a 100% Stack Exchange Network site. The owners have agreed to let us import the uses/questions and the use the domain name to get the "Electronics and Robotics" Stack Exchange off to a strong start.

It was a good match. The posts and Google ranking is a windfall to this community and using the same domain name provides a seamless experience for the existing users.

Wherever possible, we are working with the Stack Exchange 1.0 sites that have created successful communities. Generally, it is better to bring them into the Stack Exchange Network rather than shutting them down or creating competing sites. The more people we get together in one place, the better the site will be.

Comment: "And use the domain name" -> Does that mean that this question: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15 is already answered?  If so, why are we looking at the rather wordy electronics.stackexchange.com URL right now?

Comment: Glad to see them merged.  I was afraid Electronics and Robotics was going to coexist with Chiphacker and I'd have to be visiting both sites.

Comment: where is the content of the SE 1.0 site *Electronics Exchange*? (I have opened a question at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/where-is-the-content-for-electronics-exchange-stack-exchange-1-0-site)

Comment: The electronics.SE site expired several months ago and I do not know if the owner chose to export or publish their data. At the time the site went down, it had only about 120 questions and was getting barely a small trickle of activity (2-3 questions per week, maybe).

Answer (score 2):

Have the old Electronics Exchange questions been migrated in a similar way to the Chiphacker ones? Although I didn't use it much I was a member there just after I joined Chiphacker and there were a few questions which it might be worth keeping.

Comment: @Amos: no, they have not been migrated. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/where-is-the-content-for-electronics-exchange-stack-exchange-1-0-site. I agree with you: there are questions worth keeping. If you know the title (or other content) for questions some of them can still be recovered from the Google cache.

Comment: What's happened to my gravatar? Did I ask this before my bogus id had been merged into my proper one?

Answer (score -1):

Electronics Exchange is the Chiphacker 2.0 version. The name "electronics" is more generic and apropriated for this site.

Comment: Electronics Exchange was also a SE 1.0 site, which was also (I believe) merged with this version.

Comment: I agree that Electronics is really a better name than Chiphacker because my favorite questions at Chiphacker were not about circuits using integrated circuits (chips) but about those with discrete components.

Comment: @reemrevnivek: no, the content of Electronics Exchange 1.0 is not here. I checked 11 questions. Only one was here (it may have cross-posted at the time), 7 are in the Google cache and 3 are not in the Google cache. I have opened a question at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/where-is-the-content-for-electronics-exchange-stack-exchange-1-0-site

Comment: @Peter - Thanks for that question!  However, since this is technically an Area51 site at the moment, shouldn't that go on meta.stackoverflow.com?  Also, I later came to the conclusion that EE 1.0 wasn't merged with EE 2.0 (you're right, my above comment was incorrect), in researching this question: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39