# Should meta questions from the previous site(s) be moved here? [Closing]

Tags: discussion, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should we do with the questions tagged as “meta”](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/what-should-we-do-with-the-questions-tagged-as-meta)

On SE 1.0, there was no meta. page; instead, Chiphacker and EE 1.0 used a [[meta] tag](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta).  There are 15 such questions, with topics including:

- [What can or should be done to improve ChipHacker.com?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/361/what-can-or-should-be-done-to-improve-chiphacker-com)
- [What about Electronics Exchange? [closed]](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/666/what-about-electronics-exchange-closed)
- [Help us choose the new Chiphacker.com Logo [closed]](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/671)
- [Merging Electronics Exchange with Chiphacker](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1256/merging-electronics-exchange-with-chiphacker)
- [What about Electronics and Robotics in Area51?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3876/what-about-electronics-and-robotics-in-area51)
- [[meta] Will Chiphacker survive Stackexchange 2.0?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3876/what-about-electronics-and-robotics-in-area51)
- [[Meta]What part of the world are you from?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/metawhat-part-of-the-world-are-you-from)

Some of these are clearly about Chiphacker or Electronics Exchange 1.0, and probably should be kept for historical reasons, and to answer questions like [this one](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/).

On SE 2.0, this meta site is where those questions really belong.  However, moving those questions from their current location will break URLs, like the ones in the list above.

Do we want to move these over?

Comment: Wait, I can't close?  I typed this up before I realized that O Engenheiro had made a duplicate.  Oh...mod status is gone.  Sad day.

Comment: I thought migrating questions kept their urls working...

Comment: @Eric - I was unaware of this feature.  However, the whole question is moot, due to Robert Cartaino's answer here: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9/what-should-we-do-with-the-questions-tagged-as-meta/10#10